# How to read data from serial port? Python

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, pyserial

Hi please bear my basic question as I am new to python. 
I am trying to read data from serial port. Basically serial port is a USB port converted to serial port virtually. I am using arduino. 
First i tried this code:

```
while(True):
    ser=serial.Serial('COM6',9600)
    bytoread=ser.inWaiting()
    val=ser.read(bytoread)
```

But it gave me error.

```
Permission Error(13,Access is denied, none 5)
```

But when i changed my code to

```
while(True):
    ser=serial.Serial()
    ser.baudrate=19600
    ser.port='COM6'
    ser
    ser.open()
    bytoread=ser.inWaiting()
    val=ser.read(bytoread)
```

Permission error did not come but program is always busy connecting the port. I waited for many minutes but it never moved forward. What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do something like :

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM6', 9600, timeout=None)

while True:
    data = ser.readline()
```

you can't put `ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600, timeout=None)` in your `while` loop because it will permanently (re)create the connection...